# how do I break a choice command's message in multiple lines in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I would need to make a list of choices with text, but I also need the elements of the list to be in different lines; is there a way to do it from inside the choice command or I need to have a list before the choice command, made with echo commands?
like so:

```
echo first member
echo second member
choice /c [<Choice1><Choice2><…>] /n /m "third member"
```

---

or is there a way to make a similar thing, but with only the choice command?

Comment: Plain and simple.  Echo the list to the screen before the choice command. You literally answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to know if there was a better way to do it

Comment: Why do you want that? Is using `echo` not simple enough?

Comment: The [K.I.S.S. principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) defined.

Comment: I know, i was wondering if there was another method, more efficient or elegant

Comment: ... that is _not_ explained in the `choice /?` help screen? I think the answer should be obvious...

Comment: Well, I checked that, but it only covered the basic syntax...

Comment: Err... No. The help screen that show the `command /?` form contains _all_ switches and options of such a command. Do you think that there are additional options that can be reviewed just in a sort of "secret documents"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than what you've already provided in your question, there's also this option:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(Set LF=^
%Null%
)
Choice /C 123 /N /M "One!LF!Two!LF!Three"
Echo %ERRORLEVEL%
Pause
```

*I'm not sure it would be considered better though!*

Comment: plus one for the italicized disclaimer at the end :-)

Comment: Interesting, so the "^" character prompts a line break? and why are you using exclamation marks to call the variable? Lastly, why are you setting EnableDelayedExpansion, what does it do?